# Add trailing and leading spaces to characters in string if not existing already

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string

I want to add trailing and leading spaces to all '/' characters, but only when there aren't spaces in those positions already, so I can't simply do a `.Replace("/"," / ")`

So string
`This / is fine / these should be replaced hi/there/nice/to/meet/you`
should become
`This / is fine / these should be replaced hi / there / nice / to / meet / you`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split and then rejoin after trimming the results. This is assuming you don't care about the possible loss of whitespaces, should there be more than one after each other.

```
Dim parts = Text.Split("/"c).Select(Function(t) t.Trim)
Dim result = String.Join(" / ", parts)
```